# show table with parameter crystal report in visual basic.net

Tags: crystal-reports

hello I'm new to crystal report, and I'm a student. I use crystal report in VB.net 2015 for report data, I want to show crystal report after push the button and choose list in combo box. So, if I choose list "report1" in combo box and then push the button, crystal report will be show two tables(date/time and value1), and if I choose list "report2" in combo box and then push the button, crystal report will be show two tables(date/time and value2).

Can you show me how to make this conditiion?

thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: for now, I just try to manipulate it by stacking the table into one then I suppress with field parameters that can be enabled by vb.net program